# C++ Initilaztion of Vector of Classes

Tags: c++, vector

I have a Class

```
class MAC {
  private :
    int mac_address;
  public:
    int mac_access;
    MAC() {mac_address = 10;}
    MAC(int m_add,int m_axs):mac_address(m_add),mac_access(mac_access) {};

};
```

And I want to create vectors of this class and have the initialization like this

```
int main()
{
  C m_c;
  std::cout<<m_c.m_a.a << std::endl;
  MAC a(9,3),b(4,5);
  std::vector<MAC> m_arr;
  m_arr(4,5);
}
```

When I compile I get this error

```
constructor.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
constructor.cpp:63:12: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<MAC>) (int, int)’
```

Basically I am confused how can I give most of the function which a vector of `int` or `char` gives?

To clear the confusion I want my class to behave same as when we do something like this

```
std::vector<int> a (4,100);
```

but currently I cant do

```
std::vector<MAC> m_mac(4,100);
```

Comment: *How* do you want to initialize the vector? I.e. how many elemenys, and with what values, do you want it to contain after initialization?

Comment: I want to have vector initialization like MAC a(4,3) which will allocate memory for 4 and initialize them with 3. I want to have same initialization syntax if I would have had a int vector.

Comment: Think about what you are asking because it makes absolutely no sense. You can't initialize a `MAC` "with 3".

Answer (score -3):

```
class MAC {
private :
    int mac_address;
public:
    int mac_access;
    MAC(int arg_mac_address = 10):mac_address(arg_mac_address){}
    MAC(int m_add,int m_axs):mac_address(m_add),mac_access(mac_access) {};

};

int main()
{
    /*C m_c;
    std::cout<<m_c.m_a.a << std::endl;*/
    MAC a(9,3),b(4,5);
    std::vector<MAC> m_arr(4, 5);
}
```

Comment: You may want to state your assumption that the `arg_mac_address` is what the OP is initializing to 3. I dont think this is actually what the OP wants though.

Comment: @Ben:@kartik wants to allocate memory for 4 and initialize them with 3.I just initialize them with 5.

Comment: how do you know that the OP wants to set the `arg_mac_address`